# CL compiler unable to pick absolute include paths in cygdrive

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction, cygwin, include-path

I am pretty new to using cygwin and using CL compiler over cygwin.
(This is because of my project requirement).

I am actually facing an issue with the include paths, picked up by the cl compiler. 
We use makefiles for building the project.

The makefile automatically takes the absolute paths 
(e.g., /cygdrive/m/username/project_name/include/) 
and provides it as argument to /I (include option) of CL compiler.

But Cl Compiler is unable to find the header files in this path, whereas the header files are actually present in that path.

On the contrary if I change the makefile to provide relative path
(e.g., ../src/../project_name/include/ without starting from /cygdrive/m/username), then it is able to find and include the header files from this path ...(These are the same header files that were referred by absolute path earlier).

I am not sure why CL compiler is unable to find and include the header files when absolute path is given in /I option.

Is there any other option or any other way to provide Include paths when used in  Cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'cygpath`  in your makefile to convert the format of the file.  For the particular example you provided the command shown below will work.

```
INC_DIR=$(shell cygpath -m $/cygdrive/m/username/project_name/include/)
```

After converting all the paths include the paths in your makefile as you normally would

```
-I$(INC_DIR)
```